# dragging a circle around libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having trouble getting a snippet of libGDX code to work.

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        setTouchPos();    //set the x and y values of current touch
        cam.unproject(touchPos);

        if(disc.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
            disc.x = touchPos.x - disc.radius / 2; // disc.x becomes current touch position
            disc.y = touchPos.y - disc.radius / 2; // disc.y becomes current touch position
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if one's finger moves too fast, the disc will stop moving. Somehow, the disc isn't translating fast enough to keep up with the movement it seems. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess from your code that what you try to do is to drag the disc with the pointer (finger) and you're way to achive this by checking if the pointer is inside the disc.

The problem is, that if a pointer (doesn't matter if mouse or finger) moves, you won't get every position on the way it moved but only some points (the faster it moved the lesser points you get). The pointer is more "jumping" than really moving. Image editors for example draw just lines between these points if the user guides the brush, so the painted lines ofter look more "angular" if the brush is moved fast.

Back to your problem: After you initially checked that the user want's to drag the disc, set a boolean flag. While this flag is true, move the disc to every position the pointer goes, even if the pointer is outside the disc. Only reset this flag to false when the pointer is released (onMouseUp or something).

So your code would look more like (**Pseudocode**)

```
if (disc.contains(touchPos.x, touchPos.y)) {
    dragged = true;
}

...

if (dragged) {
    disc.x = touchPos.x - disc.radius / 2; // disc.x becomes current touch position
    disc.y = touchPos.y - disc.radius / 2; // disc.y becomes current touch position
}

...

public onMouseUp() {
     dragged = false;
}
```

Comment: +1, his is a correct approach. I would also suggest taking a look at [link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/DragListener.html)

Comment: I would +1 you, but I am unable to, thank you @Sebastian for the helpful and informative answer. I am working to implement now!